# Subquery returned more than 1 value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

There are columns `name` and `fid` .. in this there is multiple comma-separated values so I try to split these but this shows an error

```
Create procedure as sp2
    @tick int
As
    Select
        Table 4.column,
        Table 5.column,
        Table 3.column,
        **--so here I used solution like this**
        (Select b.fid 
         from table2 t2 
         cross apply (Select fid = s2.retval 
                      from [udf-str-parase](t2.fid, ',' ) s2) b),
        (Select b.name 
         from table2 t2 
         cross apply (Select name = s2.retval 
                      from [udf-str-parase](t2.name, ',' ) s2) b),
        Table 6.column
    From 
        Table 2
    Inner join 
        table4 on table4.id = table5.id
    ..........
    Where 
        tick = @tick
```

My function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] 
    (@String varchar(max), @Delimiter varchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    RETURN 
        (SELECT 
             RetSeq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
             RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
         FROM
             (SELECT x = CAST('<x>'+ replace((SELECT @String as [*] For XML Path('')),@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
             CROSS APPLY 
                 x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the sub query follows `=, !=, <, <= , >, >=` or when the sub query is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT Table4.COLUMN,
       Table5.COLUMN,
       Table3.COLUMN,
       fid,
       name,
       ..
       Table6.COLUMN
FROM   Table2 t2
       INNER JOIN table
       ..
       CROSS apply [Udf-str-parase] (t2.fid, ',') f (fid)
       CROSS apply [Udf-str-parase] (t2.name, ',') n (name)
```

Comment: before where or after where?

Comment: this shows an error 'udf-Str-Parse' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: @cooluser - Did you create that function in database you are running the above query